# Is it possible to perform batch prediction with Vision coreML

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, coreml

I'm using the `Vision` framework (which is on top of `coreML`) to make predictions for a photos. Since `coreML 2` it is possible to make batch predictions (multiple photos at once) but I'm not sure if `Vision` supports it as well. At least I didn't find.

Comment: It does not appear to at this moment. Note that on iOS you don't really get a massive speed gain from batching anyway.

Comment: @Matthijs Hollemans - I saw that on Mac OS the gain is about 30%. Is it less then that on iOS and why?

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the task. If a single prediction only uses a little GPU, then the GPU will not be very busy and it will run slower. In that case, doing a batch will make the GPU do more work, which also makes it run faster. But if a single prediction already does a lot of GPU work, then the GPU will already be running at top speed. In addition, doing things in a batch means having to do less CPU <-> GPU synchronization. On the Mac that might be more expensive than on iOS because CPU and GPU use different memory. But really, the only way to know for sure is to try it and measure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes (as of iOS 12):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/2962866-predictions